# Updating active record relation time column results in 1 day difference than expected

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sql-server, datetime, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to bulk edit a datetime column on some records, leaving the time alone and only adjusting the date. The below code works unless the time is > 1800. When the record's time is > 1800, the updated date is 1 day less than desired (`Wed, 27 Jan 2021 14:25:26 CST -06:00` becomes `Wed, 26 Jan 2021 14:25:26 CST -06:00`). We're in Central Time (Dallas, TX), so I'd assume it's an issue with timezones, and I think the issue is happening in the process of structuring the new datetime.

I've tried this with `DATETIMEFROMPARTS` and the 2 options below. Same issue every time.

This is in a Rails 5 app with sql server for the db. `target_date` is formatted `yyyy-mm-dd`.

```
products_relation.update_all("
  date_column = DATEADD(
    day,
    DATEDIFF(dd, date_column, '#{target_date}'),
    date_column
  )
")
```

```
products_relation.update_all("
  date_column = CONVERT(
    datetime, 
    CONCAT('#{target_date}', ' ', CONVERT(CHAR(8), date_column, 108))
  )
")
```

Comment: I thought Rails uses GMT time for when it's stored and we have to take that into consideration by using something like `Time.use_zone('America/Denver') {...}` or w/e your timezone name is.